# Dependent trait bounds in rust

Tags: generics, rust

I want to implement a generic two-point average in rust. There are a couple of different ways to define this operation, so I've chosen to add and divide by two:

```
pub struct Test<T> {
    pub a: T,
    pub b: T,
}

impl<T> Test<T> where T: std::ops::Add, T::Output: std::ops::Div {
    pub fn avg(&self) -> T::<std::ops::Div>::Output {
        (self.a + self.b) / 2.into()
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    println!("{}", Test{a: 1, b: 3}.avg());
}
```

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling scratch v0.1.0 (/home/madphysicist/scratch/scratch)
error[E0109]: type arguments are not allowed on type parameter `T`
 --> src/main.rs:7:30
  |
7 |     pub fn avg(&self) -> T::<std::ops::Div>::Output {
  |                          -   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type argument not allowed
  |                          |
  |                          not allowed on type parameter `T`
  |
note: type parameter `T` defined here
 --> src/main.rs:6:6
  |
6 | impl<T> Test<T> where T: std::ops::Add, T::Output: std::ops::Div {
  |      ^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0109`.
error: could not compile `scratch` (bin "scratch") due to previous error
```

I tried to add more generic types like this:

```
...
impl<T, U> Test<T> where T: std::ops::Add, U: T::Output + std::ops::Div {
    pub fn avg(&self) -> U::Output {
...
```

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling scratch v0.1.0 (/home/madphysicist/scratch/scratch)
error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Output` in `T`
 --> src/main.rs:6:50
  |
6 | impl<T, U> Test<T> where T: std::ops::Add, U: T::Output + std::ops::Div {
  |                                                  ^^^^^^ not found in `T`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0405`.
error: could not compile `scratch` (bin "scratch") due to previous error
```

So how do I express the idea that I want the input to implement `Add` and have its `Output` attribute support `Div`, and that the output of the `Div` operation will be the output type of the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to indicate restrictions on an associated type of a type is `<T as Trait1>::Ty: Trait2`.

```rust
use std::ops::{Add, Div};

pub struct Test<T> {
    pub a: T,
    pub b: T,
}

impl<T> Test<T> where T: Add, T::Output: Div {  // `<T as Add> is implied here...
    pub fn avg(&self) -> <<T as Add>::Output as Div>::Output {  // but not here
        (self.a + self.b) / 2.into()
    }
}
```

This then leads to the error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<T as Add>::Output: From<{integer}>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:31
   |
10 |         (self.a + self.b) / 2.into()
   |                               ^^^^ the trait `From<{integer}>` is not implemented for `<T as Add>::Output`
   |
   = note: required for `{integer}` to implement `Into<<T as Add>::Output>`
```

which is sensible; you need a way to get a `T` from `2`. You probably want something simple like `T: From<u8>` (a more general bound than, say, `From<i32>`) and then replacing `2` with `2_u8`.

If you want this to be as general as possible (since e.g., `i8` is not `From<u8>`) you could do something like the following, although it's probably overkill:

```rust
impl<T> Test<T> where T: Add + From<bool> + Copy, T::Output: Div {
    pub fn avg(&self) -> <<T as Add>::Output as Div>::Output {
        let one = T::from(true);
        let two = one + one;
        (self.a + self.b) / two
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I can live without supporting `i8` for now. Much appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't you want something like `<<T as Add>::Output> as Div<U>`, with `U: From<u8>`?

Comment: Instead of using `bool`, you can use `num-traits`'s [`One`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/identities/trait.One.html).